# NodeJS/Knex Creating Json Response

Tags: json, node.js, postgresql, express, knex.js

I'm currently using NodeJS with knex (Postgresql) for database stuff.

**Problem:**

Imagine the following two tables in database:

**Table 1**

---

```
PROJECT
id (pk)
name
```

**Table 2**

---

```
EMPLOYEE
id (pk)
name
project_id (fk)
```

I want to create a json-response to the user that looks like the following:

```
{
  projects: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'emxample 1',
      employees: [
       {
         id: 1,
         name: 'example 1'
       },
       {
         id: 2,
         name: 'example 2'
       }
      ]
    }
  ] 
}
```

and so on.

Making a query like:

```
let query = knex('project').select('project.*', 'employee.*').join('employee', 'employee.project_id', '=', 'project.id');

query.then((projects) => { res.json(projects); });
```

And using `res.json()` does not return an array of `employees`. What is the way to go to achieve that?

Comment: Show more context code. Where/how are you calling `res.json()`?

Comment: I call it directly after the query is executed (see updated example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL responses are flat tables by their nature so in addition to knex you will need an external lib which can reconstruct flat information to nested objects.

Most of the ORM libraries know how to do it. For example **[objection.js](http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/)** which is built on top of knex uses `.eager()` to fetch nested relations. With objection.js ORM the query would look like this `Project.query().where('id', 1).eager('employees')`

Comment: You are right. I would have loved if it could be done somehow using knex without an external library (which of course is possible - but not in reasonable time). I ended up using bookshelf.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend bookshelf for anyone, but good luck. Knex is lower level lib which shouldn't know anything about object hierarchies, just plain SQL.